# How to trigger 404 in Magento 1 from a block or helper?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, 404

I would like to redirect the user to 404 when an error occurs from a block or helper. 
In the controller i can do it like this:

```
$this->norouteAction();
return;
```

I would like to do the same thing from a block or helper . How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

This should work in a helper. I believe it would happen the same in a block

```
return Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('XXXX');
```

Change XXXX with **no_route**, or your custom path to 404 page